# how to retrieve curl data into php

Tags: php, curl, yii

Hi I am trying to get curl data from yii file to php but unable to get any data and restfulapi client shows everytime "Response does not contain any data."
I want to retrieve data from my yii file to php file

here is my yii code

```
public function actionMakeWebPaytmPayment()
{
    $this->checkAuth();
    if (!isset($this->requestData->booking_id) || 
        !isset($this->requestData->user_id) || 
        !isset($this->requestData->invoice_price) || 
                    !isset($this->requestData->user_mobile) || 
                    !isset($this->requestData->user_mail) || 
        !trim($this->requestData->booking_id) ||
        !trim($this->requestData->user_id) ||  
        !trim($this->requestData->invoice_price) || 
                    !trim($this->requestData->user_mobile) ||
                    !trim($this->requestData->user_mail)){
            $this->sendErrorResponse(''
                , Constants::API_INVALID_RECHARGE_CREDIT_PAYLOAD_CODE
                , Constants::API_INVALID_RECHARGE_CREDIT_PAYLOAD_MESSAGE);
    }

       else
       {
          $paytmUrl='http://tooler.in/PaytmKit/pgRedirect.php';
          $data = json_encode(array("booking_id" => $this->requestData->booking_id ,'user_id' => $this->requestData->user_id, 'invoice_price' => $this->requestData->invoice_price,'user_mobile'=> $this->requestData->user_mobile,'user_mail'=> $this->requestData->user_mail));

          try {
        $output = Yii::app()->curl->post($paytmUrl, $data);
        $data = json_decode($output);
                    echo $data;
                    exit;
    }catch(Exception $ex){
                echo $ex;
            }
       }     
}
```

and here is php file in this server in which I am trying to retrieve data

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// following files need to be included
require_once("./lib/config_paytm.php");
require_once("./lib/encdec_paytm.php");
echo 'test';
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input= var_dump(json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE )); 
echo $input;
print_r($input);
exit();
$decoded = var_dump(json_decode($data, true));
print_r($decoded);
exit();
?>
```

no echo or print command is working only thing I get is "Response does not contain any data."
any help please